# ffmpeg adding live audio to looping slideshow

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I've been working on this for a few weeks now....lol
For now, I've just been creating a `.mp4`, but eventually want to stream this to YouTube.

Bottom Line is: it's just a live radio broadcast with a looping series of `.jpg` pictures.

This works for the audio input:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -t 10 alsaout.wav
```

This works for the slideshow:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 30 -framerate 1/2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=10,format=yuv420p" SlideOut.mp4
```

Now if I could only combine those 2 into one output, I'd be a camper that is HAPPY....lol.

Tried this, but the video created doesn't play. Also it just keeps going and I have to re-boot to kill it:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 30 -framerate 1/2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=10,format=yuv420p" SlideOut.mp4
```

Hoping someone can lead me down the right path.....the one with the flowers and the butterflies zipping around...

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I made one small change and it seems to be working now. Added -t 20 before the output........

Now hoping this puppy will stream..........Thanks guys!!!